# How would this Geometry proof be solved?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

This proof was from an assessment that I took, and I wasn't able to answer any the answers correctly. Since I was not given any feedback on why my answers were incorrect, it would be great if someone could walk me through the steps.

[image: problem]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! **Help us help you.** You should give your own answers to the exercise, even though they were incorrect. (Possibly, your grader made errors in assessing your work.) And you should explain your own thoughts on those answers. (Maybe you had a simple misunderstanding that can be easily identified and corrected.) The more information you can provide helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $AD = 8$

2) $AD = BC$

4) Given

5) Substitution (or transitive) property of congruence

Comment: Statement (2) is incorrect. (If it were correct, then statement (3), which says exactly what you wrote, would be redundant.) Instead, we want $AD=BC$, a statement of *equality of numbers* (in this case, *lengths*) derived by substitution using $AD=8$ and $BC=8$ (each of which is a statement of equality of numbers). Then, this *equality of numbers* implies the *congruence of segments* statement in (3) via the definition of segment congruence.

Comment: Indeed Blue, thanks.